# Designing - How do you approach finding the right font for your game?

Tags: game-design, game-development

I'm working on making my own card game, and I'm wondering how to approach picking a particular font. I know that this is partially subjective, however, I also know that from a designer's stand point this can be very technical and methodical.

Anyone have a 'best practice' for this?

Comment: [Graphics Design.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) may be able to give you better answers than we can here.

Comment: There is a tag on Graphics Design Stack Exchange devoted to font recommendations (called font-recommendations), so it seems like a no brainer to migrate this question. You might do some research what fonts popular card games use before you ask your question. Magic: the Gathering and Munchkin are good places to start, as they are on opposite ends of the spectrum when it comes to choosing fonts.

Comment: I agree that Graphics SE may be helpful. However, I believe this is also on-topic here, so I'm not going to migrate. There is a legitimate perspective here from the point of view of game designers (e.g. what are they aiming for with a font, what resources are available, etc.) which goes beyond the technicalities of choice of font.

Comment: @ire_and_curses you need knowledge of which font properties (ligatures, serifs, kerning) affect readability at certain distances and angles. This question is 100% Graphics Design SE.

Comment: I've raised this closure on meta here: [Should this question about fonts be closed?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1315/50)

Comment: @freekvd - I think you may be missing my point. See Joe's answer below, which is at the level of a font user (specifically a game designer), *not* a graphics designer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't include enough detail. I can imagine multiple textbook chapters being written over what fonts to use in general. Details that might help narrow the question down include how much text will be on the cards, card size, what type of game it is, where the cards will be located during gameplay, how long the players have to look at the cards, whether they can refer back to them later, etc. The more detail, the better.

Comment: @Rainbolt That doesn't make the question off topic; that makes it unclear (not enough detail), or too broad (answers will be too large).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of response - I was never notified that anyone responded, so sorry!
My point was more the bigger question and not just, "pick a font". I've been told many times that the font ties the whole game together. That's a big question. My question was more guided towards, what mood does giving a serif do and how do I tie that into the game. Kind of what ire_and_curses said.

Comment: This is not a proper answer, but make sure you take a font that contains foreigner characters such as "é", "ç" or "ö". Many fonts don't contain them and if by chance you want to translate your game, you will have to change font.

Answer (score 11):

When I've put out [games](http://lumenaris.com/games.html) in the past, there have usually been two goals in font selection:

- Fonts that are easy to read at the angle the player will be looking from.
- Fonts that evoke the setting of the game.

For example, *[The Golden Wilderness](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/134419/golden-wilderness)* is set in colonial California, so [a typeface that was widely used in the 1700s](http://iginomarini.com/fell/) helps evoke the setting.  There's basically nothing you need to read during the game that isn't upright and in your hand (and that you have plenty of time to read), so readability isn't the issue.

[image: Igino Marini's DW Pica]

*[Leaving Earth](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/173064/leaving-earth)*, on the other hand, has many cards sitting all around the table that need to be understood by the players.  Readability helps the game play more smoothly, so a clean font that's easy to read from multiple angles is needed.

[image: Liberation Sans]

Which particular fonts meet these criteria for your game all depends on the specifics.

Acquiring those fonts is another matter.  There are plenty of free fonts out there, but don't be afraid to spend a little money on a good, professional font.  The best professional fonts are designed with an eye for many tiny details (like kerning and ligatures) that you (assuming you're not a typographer) shouldn't have to worry about.

If you're just using a font for a bit of flavor, things like kerning might not matter too much (though it pains a typography enthusiast like me to say it).  If you're using a font for your main title/logo, or for extended blocks of reading material, those small details matter much more.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Such a good response!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great article by Daniel Solis:

http://danielsolisblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/5-graphic-design-and-typography-tips.html

Comment: Hi Joseph DR, welcome to the site. It looks like a good article, but link-only answers are discouraged (and attract negative votes), because the link might disappear in the future. Would you summarise the main points of the article here?